# Адаптация под мобильное устройство, Google не видит что он адаптивен при проверке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, joomla, адаптивная-верстка

Есть сайт, https://elenanovias.com/en/ я адаптировал его под моб., но search.google говорит что сайт не адаптивен

viewport есть.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ,  maximum-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=yes  ">`

Я делал сайт на joomla 2.5. Я кое что прочитал, может в этом вся и проблема?
Joomla! 2.5 - конец жизни с декабря 2014 года. Joomla! 3.x является мобильным для мобильных устройств

В стилях я юзаю

`@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {`

а не

`@media (max-width: 768px)`

Надо больше информации, пишите.
[image: my site]

[image: google]

[image: еще с гуглом картинка]

Comment: В <head> стоит <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    ?

Comment: Когда пишите -"Есть сайт" нужно писать адрес сайта

Comment: @Arcadiy сейчас закину

Comment: @Arcadiy есть, добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: @Arcadiy Я кое что прочитал, может в этом вся и проблема?  Joomla! 2.5 - конец жизни с декабря 2014 года. Joomla! 3.x является мобильным для мобильных устройств.

Comment: Поставьте тот, что я написал вьюпорт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в файл robots.txt следующее

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.js
Allow: /*.css
```

Comment: Слеш *
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.js
Allow: /*.css
или
или
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: *.css
Allow: *.js

Comment: Добавляйте в том виде в котором я написал в конец файла. Это должно открыть доступ для поисковика к файлам СSS и JS так как по умолчанию они в Joomla закрыты.

Comment: Проблема была в `robots.txt`, но не `.css` и `.js`. Но вы подсказали в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: Так напишите в чем была проблема, чтобы и другие на будущее знали.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ. @ДмитрийНиколаенко - подсказал куда двигаться.

Проблема была в `robors.txt`. Google.console не мог получить все стили, я прописал абсолютный путь: `/folder/folder/folder/style.css`, и вуаля.

Я этот проект (3-летней давности) получил от другого разраба, и там было оч. много мусора.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.css //такой путь много файлов пропускал(хотя должен работать)
Allow: /templates/elenanovias/css/style.css // с этим путем все заработало
```